# Debug .NET runtime in Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

When I attempt to "step into" code from the ASP.NET itself, nothing happens.
I suppose that VSC doesn't have the source code for it? How can I do this sort of deep debugging?

Environment:

.NET v7 with ASP.NET

IDE:   Visual Studio Code

Comment: Could you not download visual studio proper and do it there instead? I don't believe that VSC supports visual basic .net officially, though there may be a plugin you could find.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless. This is C#, no Visual Basic. My problem with Visual Studio Community Edition is that the license restrictions prevents me from using it within a commercial company. So if I want Visual Studio, I'll have to ask my boss for some money ($45 per month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to read thoroughly [the Visual Studio for Windows article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/debug-aspnetcore-source?view=aspnetcore-7.0), be familiar with both VS and VS Code, and finally translate the required settings to `launch.json`,

```json
            "justMyCode": false,
            "suppressJITOptimizations": true,
            "sourceLinkOptions": {
                "*": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            },
            "symbolOptions": {
                "searchPaths": [],
                "searchMicrosoftSymbolServer": true,
                "searchNuGetOrgSymbolServer": true
            }
```

I wrote [a complete article with more details](https://halfblood.pro/how-to-step-into-net-core-source-code-in-vs-code/).

Answer (score 0):

I had all the same settings as @LexLi and I was still unable to hit breakpoints.  I realized I had this setting set to true which was interfering with debugging: `omnisharp.enableDecompilationSupport`